# How to select all the text in a Grid cell

Tags: select, grid, dhtmlx

I'm developing an app using dhtmlxGrid and have such a question:

How can I make the full text in a cell selected when the cell is selected?

I mean when I click on the cell, and the editor opens, I would like to have all the text selected so as I could delete it or start editing at once. I've gone through the documentation, but haven't found any event or method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to add the following code to select all the text value after the edit start:

```
myGrid.attachEvent("onEditCell",function(stage,rowId,colInd){
if (stage==1 && this.editor && this.editor.obj){
this.editor.obj.select();
}
return true
})
```